# how does python indexing affect runtime of o-notation?

Tags: python, indexing, big-o

I am new to O-notation and am trying to find the worst-case runtime for some of my codes. The only issue is that I'm confused on how O-notation runs with indexing and appending so I thought I'd ask for help with the following sample codes:

```
def sums_1(L):
  n = len(L)
  tot = 0
  M = []
  for i in L[:n//2]:
    M.append(i)
  for i in L[n//2:]:
    M.extend(L)
  return sum(M)

def sums_2(s):
  def help_e(s, pos):
    if pos >= len(s):
      return ''
    return help_e(s, pos+1) + s[pos]
  return help_e(s, 0)
```

I think both codes would run o(n) times but I wanted some clarification on indexing and how that may affect the runtime, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the wiki file for the big-o notation for almost every python data-structure operations: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity